# Which type of "No Network Connectivity" warning should I use for my iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios

The app i'm developing for the app store infrequently needs network connectivity. I've already implemented a way to handle/notify the user when there is no network connection, but that only happens when they've initiated the request (click a button to make a web service call).

My question is, Does apple require a continuous check for network connectivity, i.e. their reachability example, or will the method I have implemented (checking for network connectivity only when certain actions are triggered) be acceptable for app store submission?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking for connectivity only when it's needed is sufficient.  In fact, Apple discourages using Reachability as a "pre-flight" check.  They say to just handle failure gracefully, and then use Reachability if necessary to watch for connectivity to come back.

Answer (score 1):

It is acceptable for app store submission.  In fact, I'm sure AT&T and Apple would prefer it.